# File_exists but won't include

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a file but it doesn't seem to be working - here's the entire code:

```
if (file_exists('config/categories.php')) {
    include ('config/categories.php'); 
} 

foreach ($categories as $cat_sef => $cat_name) {
    echo '<a href="'.$full_domain.$cat_sef.'" alt="#">'.$cat_name.'</a><br />';
}
```

The contents of config/categories.php is simply an array:

```
$categories = array("category-1" => "Category 1", 
"category-2" => "Category 2", 
"category-3" => "Category 3")
```

I know the file exists because the following works:

```
if (file_exists('config/categories.php')) {
    echo "file exists";
}
```

However if I replace the array in categories.php with say:

```
echo "testing";
```

Nothing will display either. So as far as I can see, the file exists but it doesn't seem to be including some how. If I rename the categories file to something else I will receive a 'no such file' error (file does not exist).

With the original code snippet, the error I get is:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: categories
```

But as you can see, it is defined in the categories.php file.

The ONLY way it works is to put the array in place of the if (file_exists) part of my code, which I don't want to do because other parts rely on that categories.php file, so I don't want to dupe an array in multiple files.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What happens if you simply `require` the file without `file_exists` check? That would seem to be more idiomatic for how you want to use it anyway.

Comment: Send output from your readfile('config/categories.php'); here.

Comment: Basics: does _categories.php_ start with `<?php`?

Comment: try to print_r( get_included_files() ); ?> after inclusion. This file should appear inside that array

Comment: put some text,html at the top of "config/categories.php"; it renders?

Comment: Yeah my categories page starts with <?php and ends with ?> I also did pring_r(get_included_files()); and it showed up as the 10th file included: /home/u5249/httpdocs/config/categories.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here :

- use `include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/categories.php')` to make sure you are including this same file and not another 'config/categories.php'
- double check that categories.php includes opening php tags like this `<?php`. Seems obvious, but I have seen this more than once in code reviews.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

You  just included $categories inside **if** operator scope, so you can't use $categories outside. Just introduce $categories before inclusion

```
$categories = null;
if (file_exists('config/categories.php')) {
    include ('config/categories.php'); 
} 

foreach ($categories as $cat_sef => $cat_name) {
    echo '<a href="'.$full_domain.$cat_sef.'" alt="#">'.$cat_name.'</a><br />';
}
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and now I get: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u5249/httpdocs/php/display_category_list_in_sidebar.php on line 21

Comment: This code was tested. So check this:
1. file categories.php starts with <?php
2. Codeblock if (file_exists('config/categories.php')) really executes, to quick check this use 'require' instead of 'include'

Answer (score 2):

`file_exists` and `include` do not looking for file in the same way. include use the `include_path` option and search for your file in differents directory.

If you really want to know if a file can be included, you should use an absolute path.

An other thing. If your `foreach ($categories` code is inside a function, you need to define the `$categories` variable as global. Because `include` are always done in the global context.

Answer (score 0):

use `include_once` if you have already included this file before.

Answer (score -1):

If your file exists then please check php.ini file and set `short_tag_open=on`. It may works.